# How to use ng-deep at media query syntax inside?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I need to bind the CSS class property value dynamically for desktop. i have using ng-deep in angular. if i use the ng-deep inside the @media query is not working.

i have tried below code in css

```
 @media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

   ::ng-deep.bs-datepicker {
    left: var(--my-var) !important;
   }

  }
```

ng-deep CSS is not working at media query syntax. where i need to place or what i need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::ng-deep` does work inside a media query... something else must be off for your specific case;

relevant **CSS** in **typeahead-basic.ts**:

```
  ::ng-deep .dropdown-menu.show { background:lightblue;}
  ::ng-deep .dropdown-item { color:red !important; }
  @media screen and (max-width:768px){
    ::ng-deep .dropdown-menu.show { background:lightgreen;}
    ::ng-deep .dropdown-item { color:orange !important; }
  }
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfkx6p)

**update**: for your [shared stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfqrby), the correct syntax is below... you gotta check your page on the widths between `1025px` and `1280px` and you will see the effect in action:

```
@media  (min-width:1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

::ng-deep .third-party-content{
  left:30px;
  position: absolute;
  color:red;
}

}
```

Comment: Not working for your scenario? Can you share an MVCE which replicates this behavior?

Comment: @Manikandan, you gotta check your page on the widths between **1025px** and **1280px** and you will see the effect in action

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Had to give up on `::ng-deep` and use `ViewEncapsulation.None`. It's so weird since `::ng-deep` did work when used without a `@media` selector

Answer (score 3):

I just found out you can do it like this in scss

```
::ng-deep.bs-datepicker {
  @media  (min-width:1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
    left:30px;
    position: absolute;
    color:red;
  }
}
```

I might be late to the conversation but eh,
If you still need it or anyone else like me still looking...
I hope it works for you too :)